# Is it possible to use MVVM Light with Entity Framework Core in a UWP project?

Tags: uwp, entity-framework-core, mvvm-light

I'm trying to use Entity Framework Core with UWP. I found this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started) from Microsoft and got it to work. In this sample, the object models are in a .Net Standard class library. However, for the project I'm working on, I need to be able to use MVVM Light's RaisePropertyChanged method in the setters of my object models. The issue I'm running into is that MVVM Light is apparently not compatible with .NET Standard 2.0, only 1.0.

MVVM Light does seem to install correctly to the class library,
[image]
 but when I try to add a using statement it doesn't work: `using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;` gives me a "The type or namespace GalaSoft could not be found." (I did also try without "GalaSoft.")

I've tried everything I can think of, and this really has me stumped. Is there any way that I can use MVVM Light with UWP and Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Did you try to install the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried installing MvvmLight 5.4.1.1 to the class library project containing the models in the sample. It appears to install successfully. (I can see in the project dependencies, under NuGet.) However, when I try to add a Using statement, Visual Studio gives me the "type or namespace cannot be found" error. Thanks.

Comment: Please include the failing "using statement" in your question.

Comment: Added using statement and more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Standard versions are always backwards compatible, so MVVM Light being .NET Standard 1.0, it makes it fully compatible with .NET Standard 2.0 libraries. You must use the .NET Standard version of MVVM Light which is here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibsStd10/

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you. The problem was that I was trying to use MvvmLightLibs instead of MvvmLightLibsStd10.