# is MVVM Light compatible with NET Core 3 WPF?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mvvm-light

I have a project that is a WPF NET Core 3 application, and I would like to use MVVM Light. But I have the following warning:

The package "MvvmLightLibs 5.4.1.1" was restored with NET Framework version 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8 instead of the target platform ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0". Perhaps the package couldn't be completly compatible with the project.

Really I have not found any odd behaviour, perhaps it is because I am using the basic features, but I would like to know if there are some way to solve this warning.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not pushing a PR to https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight ? It's probably only a few LOC to support it. Else, fork it and build your own and in the mean time open an issue to ask the author.

Comment: alreay replied on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124254/is-it-possible-to-use-mvvm-light-with-entity-framework-core-in-a-uwp-project